# Why is there a "mechas" tag when "mecha" is the proper plural?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Why is there a [mechas](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechas) tag when [mecha](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mecha) is the proper plural?
Perhaps I'm infected with incurable pedantry, but it's as glaring as wandering around and seeing references to "sheeps" and "goatses," or even "mens."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed that for you.

Comment: Upvoted because FTFY was obvs too short. :P

Comment: Danke; I appreciate it. SE is not my usual stalking grounds.

Comment: @SquidLord stick around, we're going to do some cool things!